# WSO2 XML Declaration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 to deploy a simple service.  I have a service returning the following XML:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>JOHNDOE1</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
        <LastName>DOE</LastName>
    </Employee>
    <Status>1</Status>
</Employees>
```

The problem I'm having is that there is no XML declaration.  Is there a setting that will return the response with the XML declaration included, or do I need to use the ESB response to add it?  I was hoping for something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeID>JOHNDOE1</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
        <LastName>DOE</LastName>
    </Employee>
    <Status>1</Status>
</Employees>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but seeing as I ran into the same thing just now I'll post my solution.

I needed to have a proxy service return a plain XML message without the enclosing soap envelope. I tried using `application/xml` and `text/xml` (`org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter` and `org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter` respectively) content types to no avail. Neither of these content types returned the message with the XML declaration.

The solution is to write a custom message formatter. Here's my implementation that behaves like `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter` but properly writes the XML declaration to the message.

```
package com.example.axis2.messageformatter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.axiom.om.OMOutputFormat;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter;

public class CustomApplicationXmlFormatter extends ApplicationXMLFormatter {

  @Override
  public void writeTo(MessageContext context, OMOutputFormat format, OutputStream out, boolean preserve) throws AxisFault {
    String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" + format.getCharSetEncoding() + "\"?>";
    try {
      out.write(xmlHeader.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new AxisFault("Unable to write XML declaration to output stream.", e);
    }
    super.writeTo(context, format, out, preserve);
  }
}
```

You can drop the class in a jar file to `<ESB_ROOT>/repository/components/lib`.
Additionally you need to refer to the class from the axis2 config (`<ESB_ROOT>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`) by adding the following into the message formatters portion of the file:

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/xml" class="com.example.axis2.messageformatter.CustomApplicationXmlFormatter"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kallja answered before - messageFormatter should be fixed.

I've implemented his fix as a maven-based project - available here: https://github.com/akakunin/custom-appxml-message-formatter

I've tested it with WSO2 EI 6.0.0 - it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here in case someone else stumbles upon the same issue, WSO2 now support this OOTB with the following axis2 property

`<property name="WRITE_XML_DECLARATION" scope="axis2" value="true"/>`

source for this - https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/blob/master/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/ApplicationXMLFormatter.java#L53

Answer (score -1):

How you captured SOAP message? You can use [Tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) or just add a [log mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Log+Mediator) with log level full to observe the complete the complete message. I assume you what you have observed is SOAP body. You do not need to add xml declaration etc. manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPriceResponse>
    <m:Price>34.5</m:Price>
  </m:GetStockPriceResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: -1. The answer doesn't really answer the original question, or anything even in the same ball park with it for that matter.