# How to set encoding of SOAP request in WSO2 ESB 4.9

Tags: soap, encoding, wso2-esb

I'm unable to set encoding of the request in WSO2ESB. I tried different methods:

1. Using encoding attribute of the address endpoint, but this attribute is  ignored.

`<address uri="http://we-pr-07:8080/mpi-service/service/" format="soap12" encoding="UTF-8"/>`

2. By setting messageType and CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, but these properties seems not working in version 4.9.

`<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>`

What is proper way to set encoding? Is there way to set UTF-8 as default encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure but does not an XML declaration  specify the XML version and the character encoding of the XML message.

that being the case try:

[WSO2 XML Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019908/wso2-xml-declaration)