# WSO2ESB: How to add <?xml into the message sent to POX endpoint

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm using wso2ei 6.0.0 and I have a simple task - send specific xml message via POST to the endpoint.
I have API configured like this:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="glisTest" context="/glisTest">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{sampleid}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="false"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <register />
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="post" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://localhost/manager" encoding="UTF-8" format="pox"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

But service is expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

to be inserted at the beginning and wso2 do not do it (I just added debug logging for org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire and I see it simple send

```
<register/>
```

As result, it does not recognize message as an xml and returm me error.

Question - how to tell synapse to add this special xml header to the message?

Comment: Actually I found solution in fixing ApplicationXMLFormatter described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019908/wso2-xml-declaration but probably there are some more "right" way available?

Comment: I've implemented fix as maven project - available here: https://github.com/akakunin/custom-appxml-message-formatter