# How to add a line break to the xml body in wso2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm transforming my incoming message with xslt like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Person>
            <Last-Name><xsl:value-of select="//lastname"/></Last-Name>
            <First-Name><xsl:value-of select="//firstname"/></First-Name>
    </Person>
</xsl:template>
```

**Now i want to add a line break at the end of the output (after the root tag)**, but wso2 keeps removing it for some reason.

i've tried using

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

and

```
<xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
```

and

```
        <![CDATA[

         ]]>
```

Is there any way to keep this in my output?

I'm writing the message to a xml file on my local system.

i'm new to wso2, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Did you try with adding this block `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` twice?

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani yes, i just tried it, it didn't work. The problem however is that the line break should be at the end of the message. After the root tag

Comment: can you post your sample xml as well?

Comment: Did you try adding <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text> **or** <br/> ?

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani my input is json,which looks like this:
 `{
   "firstname":"john",
   "lastname":"Doe"
}

`

Comment: @Vebbie this gives me an error in wso2: `Unexpected character '&' (code 38) in epilog; expected '<'`

Comment: You can solve the above error by using **&amp;**.. E.g. <xsl:text>&amp;#13;</xsl:text>

Answer (score 0):

I asked some wso2 veteran and apparently this isn't possible with wso2. 
Wso2 will always remove it to be able encapsulate it.
I was able to solve it using a custom message formatter.
similar to this post: [stack overflow post describing how to add a xml declaration to the beginning of a xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019908/wso2-xml-declaration)